# How to type hint FormData for use in URLSearchParams?

Tags: typescript

I need to make an ajax call using jQuery and I require to pass the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This means I need to pass URL search query as a parameter. However, my application builds the data using `FormData` object. I have found online a nice trick to convert it to a query string like this:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('someField', "someValue");
let queryString = new URLSearchParams(data).toString();
```

This works perfect for what I need to achieve. However, I am writing the code in TypeScript and it complains that the parameter passed to the `URLSearchParams` constructor is of the wrong type.

```
Argument of type 'FormData' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | string[][] | Record<string, string> | URLSearchParams | undefined'.
  Property 'sort' is missing in type 'FormData' but required in type 'URLSearchParams'.(2345)
input.tsx(6, 18): 'sort' is declared here.
```

[See online on playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAJghmMQLwQHYgO4QGIHsBOAtgCJwwAUAlANwBQs8AdDAA7MgpRkDkAzjgSCwBLEMChcANBABEfAQDUYwAK4hp1GjVCRleYElQYIAVQBKAGQDKIGHgDGACwAKtmAR5l6MCgzA5LYHhCKADmlLQ0djgofKAMwDhhusDUQA)

Is there any way to avoid the error in TypeScript since this is a valid JavaScript operation?

Comment: Just noting that this would be fixed by an open issue in TS if it/when it happens. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19806

Answer (score 5):

Well assuming the library is typed incorrectly and this is a valid construction you can just tell typescript to screw off with a cast to any:

```
let url = new URLSearchParams(data as any).toString();
```